# How to 3D plot a parametric curve WITH orthographic projections?

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

How to generate a 3D plot of a parametric curve with the orthographic projections on the inside walls of the 3D plot, as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Cb9MsrnzrU)?

I can generate a 3D plot of the curve using the `plot3` function but I am lost how to create the blue orthographic projections on the inner walls of the cube ...and the red dashed lines.

[image]

P.S.
Also, how to generate the 3 separate "Coordinate Functions" plots (not shown on the diagram above but shown in the video) ...and how to synchronize them together during the animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this took a lot of time to write.

```
clear;clc;close all
t = 0:0.01:6;

x = cos(5*t);
y = sin(5*t);
z = t;

%for x,y,z as as general function of t
xmin = min(x);
xmax = max(x);

ymin = min(y);
ymax = max(y);

zmin = min(z);
zmax = max(z);

orangeColorRGB = [0.8500 0.3250 0.0980];

%3D plot
plot3DSubplot = subplot(3,2,[1 3 5]);
view(3)
grid on
title('Parametric curve in R^3')
xlabel('x(t)')
ylabel('y(t)')
zlabel('z(t)')

xyProjectionOffset = -0.5;
xzProjectionOffset = 1.5;
yzProjectionOffset = 1.5;

xlim([xmin max(xmax, yzProjectionOffset)])
ylim([ymin max(ymax, xzProjectionOffset)])
zlim([min(zmin ,xyProjectionOffset) zmax])

curve3D_marker = animatedline(plot3DSubplot,x(1),y(1),z(1),'Marker','o','Color','magenta'); %marker in 3D
curve3D = animatedline(plot3DSubplot, x(1),y(1),z(1),'Color','magenta','LineStyle','-','LineWidth',2); %3D curve

curve3D_projectedToXY = animatedline(plot3DSubplot,x(1),y(1),xyProjectionOffset,'Color','blue','LineStyle','-','LineWidth',2); %projection on xy
curve3D_projectionStraightLineToXY = animatedline(plot3DSubplot,x(1),y(1),z(1),'Color',orangeColorRGB,'LineStyle','--','LineWidth',2); %projection on xy 

curve3D_projectedToXZ = animatedline(plot3DSubplot,x(1),xzProjectionOffset,z(1),'Color','blue','LineStyle','-','LineWidth',2); %projection on xz
curve3D_projectionStraightLineToXZ = animatedline(plot3DSubplot,x(1),y(1),z(1),'Color',orangeColorRGB,'LineStyle','--','LineWidth',2); %projection on xy 

curve3D_projectedToYZ = animatedline(plot3DSubplot,yzProjectionOffset,y(1),z(1),'Color','blue','LineStyle','-','LineWidth',2); %projection on yz
curve3D_projectionStraightLineToYZ = animatedline(plot3DSubplot,x(1),y(1),z(1),'Color',orangeColorRGB,'LineStyle','--','LineWidth',2); %projection on xy 

%x plot
xPlot = subplot(3,2,2);
grid on
title('Coordinates')
ylabel('cos(5t)')
xlim([t(1) t(end)])
ylim([xmin xmax])
xCoordinate = animatedline(xPlot,t(1),x(1),'Color','blue');
xCoordinate_projectedValue = animatedline(xPlot,t(1),x(1),'Color',orangeColorRGB,'LineStyle','--');
xCoordinateMarker = animatedline(xPlot,t(1),x(1),'Color','blue','Marker','o');

%y plot
yPlot = subplot(3,2,4);
grid on
ylabel('sin(5t)')
xlim([t(1) t(end)])
ylim([ymin ymax])
yCoordinate = animatedline(yPlot,t(1),y(1),'Color','blue');
yCoordinate_projectedValue = animatedline(yPlot,t(1),y(1),'Color',orangeColorRGB,'LineStyle','--');
yCoordinateMarker = animatedline(yPlot,t(1),y(1),'Color','blue','Marker','o');

%z plot
zPlot = subplot(3,2,6);
grid on
ylabel('t')
xlim([t(1) t(end)])
ylim([zmin zmax])
zCoordinate = animatedline(zPlot,t(1),z(1),'Color','blue');
zCoordinate_projectedValue = animatedline(zPlot,t(1),z(1),'Color',orangeColorRGB,'LineStyle','--');
zCoordinateMarker = animatedline(zPlot,t(1),z(1),'Color','blue','Marker','o');

for i=2:length(t)

    % 3D plot & projections
    addpoints(curve3D,x(i),y(i),z(i))
    clearpoints(curve3D_marker)
    addpoints(curve3D_marker,x(i),y(i),z(i))

    %XY projection
    addpoints(curve3D_projectedToXY,x(i),y(i),xyProjectionOffset)
    clearpoints(curve3D_projectionStraightLineToXY)
    addpoints(curve3D_projectionStraightLineToXY,[x(i) x(i)],[y(i) y(i)],[xyProjectionOffset z(i)])

    %XZ projection
    addpoints(curve3D_projectedToXZ,x(i),xzProjectionOffset,z(i))
    clearpoints(curve3D_projectionStraightLineToXZ)
    addpoints(curve3D_projectionStraightLineToXZ,[x(i) x(i)],[xzProjectionOffset y(i)],[z(i) z(i)])

    %YZ projection
    addpoints(curve3D_projectedToYZ,1.5,y(i),z(i))
    clearpoints(curve3D_projectionStraightLineToYZ)
    addpoints(curve3D_projectionStraightLineToYZ,[yzProjectionOffset x(i)],[y(i) y(i)],[z(i) z(i)])

    %2D x plot
    addpoints(xCoordinate,t(i),x(i))
    clearpoints(xCoordinate_projectedValue)
    addpoints(xCoordinate_projectedValue,[t(1) t(i)],[x(i) x(i)])
    clearpoints(xCoordinateMarker)
    addpoints(xCoordinateMarker,t(i),x(i))

    %2D y plot
    addpoints(yCoordinate,t(i),y(i))
    clearpoints(yCoordinate_projectedValue)
    addpoints(yCoordinate_projectedValue,[t(1) t(i)],[y(i) y(i)])
    clearpoints(yCoordinateMarker)
    addpoints(yCoordinateMarker,t(i),y(i))

    %2D z plot
    addpoints(zCoordinate,t(i),z(i))
    clearpoints(zCoordinate_projectedValue)
    addpoints(zCoordinate_projectedValue,[t(1) t(i)],[z(i) z(i)])
    clearpoints(zCoordinateMarker)
    addpoints(zCoordinateMarker,t(i),z(i))

    drawnow
end
```

***Outside the for-loop:***

1. Define your subplots.
2. Define your lines in a somewhat object-oriented approach. Define lines with [`animatedline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline.html?s_tid=doc_ta)
   including their
   [properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html?searchHighlight=line%20properties&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)
   (color, linewidth etc).
3. Define lines with `animatedline` with the intention to use only the marker.

***Inside the for-loop:***

1. Add the new points to those lines using [`addpoints`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpoints.html?s_tid=doc_ta).
2. Regarding the projections to the xy,yz,xz planes:
   The projection of a point (x0,y0,z0) to the xy plane defined by z = -2 is (x0,y0,-2).  Therefore when you have a point (x,y,z) you project to the correct plane in the same way.
3. For the vertical lines that connect the current point to the projection, at every update to the plot remove previous points and redraw them. That's why I first call
   [`clearpoints`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearpoints.html?s_tid=doc_ta)
   to remove any previous points and then `addpoints` to add 2 points for a straight line from the projection to the actual (x,y,z) point.
4. For the "marker-lines", again `clearpoints` and then add the new point.
5. *After adding the points to all the lines*, call
   [`drawnow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html?s_tid=doc_ta)
   before the next loop iteration for all lines to be updated at the same time (and for the updates to appear synchronized).